# how to configure socket.io 1.3.7 to use websocket first

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

after upgrading socket.io to 1.3.7

```
io.set("transports", ["websocket", "xhr-polling"]);
```

doesn't work anymore, where do I configure those options?
(I can't find this information in official docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure transport preferences like this:

```
// server
var io = require('socket.io')({
  transports : [ 'websocket', 'xhr-polling' ]
});
```

By default, `socket.io@1` will try to upgrade to web sockets if they are available, but initially, the client will always try to connect using XHR/JSONP, and upgrade to web sockets if available.

This behaviour can be confusing (it confused me the first time I used it), because it looks like it's XHR-polling. It's documented [here](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/):

> Socket.IO never assumes that `WebSocket` will just work, because in practice there’s a good chance that it won’t. Instead, it establishes a connection with XHR or JSONP right away, and then attempts to **upgrade** the connection to WebSocket. Compared to the fallback method which relies on timeouts, this means that none of your users will have a degraded experience.

Comment: how can I determine that connection was upgraded?

Comment: @Herokiller after the initial XHR handshaking, the XHR requests stop (which means that websocket took over). Also, you can watch the websocket data flowing in your browser's dev tools (in Chrome, you can find them in the _Network_ tab, and select `WS`).

Comment: in firefox console I keep seeing 'polling' request, how can I debug, why it's not websocket yet?

Comment: @Herokiller no idea why it's unable to upgrade. Are you running your Node server behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

```
var socket = require('socket.io')({
  transports : ["websocket", "xhr-polling"]
});
```