# socket.io - ipad latest iOS xhr polling

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I have an application using latest socket.io. On an iPad using the latest iOS, I noticed that the transport selected is xhr-polling. I was under the impression that websockets were fully [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) on mobile safari.

Out of curiosity, I was wondering why xhr-polling is chosen, when it appears that websockets are supported on that platform?

Comment: What version of safari is on your ipad?

Comment: The version number is 11

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133530/how-to-configure-socket-io-1-3-7-to-use-websocket-first).

> Socket.IO never assumes that WebSocket will just work, because in practice there’s a good chance that it won’t. Instead, it establishes a connection with XHR or JSONP right away, and then attempts to upgrade the connection to WebSocket. Compared to the fallback method which relies on timeouts, this means that none of your users will have a degraded experience.

Also, from the README on the Offical Socket.io GitHub page:

> Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed.

Comment: By why does it stay on polling when sockets should be supported? Must be another criteria that affects it? Thank-you

Comment: On the Socket.io server-side, you can explicitly declare whether or not to use the websocket protocol, so it depends on how the server is configured.